# Insert failure for multiple tables on bad server

Tags: php, mysql

I made a web application that `onclick` event of submit button saves the values coming from same form to 3 different tables. The problem i am facing is that when there is bad server or internet disconnect after user click on submit button then in some tables values get saved and in some it do not due to which my whole web application gives wrong output for reporting. Kindly let me know how to deal with such sort of issue. One solution i have in mind is to use one table instead of three but its a worst case scenario. Any help would be extremely appreciated Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) to ensure your updates are atomic. [Here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm) is a link to some documentation that includes examples.

Comment: So how this works in above link there's not any code help. I have a concept of transaction but in theory only. I think its being done in ATM machines and the like

Comment: Transactions are a feature of the database platform that allow you to group multiple database operations to ensure that they all succeed or all fail. That is, they are atomic. Google MySQL transactions and you will find plenty of code to do this.

Comment: To give some more explanation to the idea of "transaction", it makes sure a group of sql statements are all carried out, or all changes are reverted. It is called "transaction" because it is likely to be used in a database for a bank so that the bank doesn't end up deducting money from one account and not adding money to the other account in a real-world TRANSACTION